# How can I use 'system pwd' command with MySql CONCAT() function?

Tags: mysql, concat

How can I use 'system pwd' command with MySql CONCAT() function? I tried

```
select concat('test', system pwd);
```

gives me

ERROR 1583 (42000): Incorrect parameters in the call to native function 'concat'

Is there any way? My database version 5.1

Comment: What is "system pwd"? What you want do it?

Comment: 'system pwd' gives me the present working directory, when I run it from mysql command prompt, it works fine, but when I am trying to concatenate this command with concat() function, I can't find a way

Comment: And why would you need to know the current working directory of the server anyway?

Comment: I just wondered if I could do that ;), anyway, thanks for your interest, jynus gives a good explanation of my query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`system`** is not a recognized MySQL server command. This will only work on the MySQL command line interface "mysql". With a command like this:

```
mysql> system pwd
/tmp
```

you will get the client's current directory, nothing to do with the server. You cannot use that information on server side, for executing queries. If you want to concat the `pwd` with something else, use a script at client side (bash, php). For example:

```
$ echo $(pwd)test
/tmptest
$ mysql  -e "SELECT concat('$(pwd)', 'test')" # there is not reason to do this at all
+------------------------+
| concat('/tmp', 'test') |
+------------------------+
| /tmptest               |
+------------------------+
```

While there is a custom non-standard [UDF library](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys) to make MySQL server interact with the operating system, I do not see a valid use in your case.

If you want to know the directory where MySQL is installed, where the datafiles are, etc., you can execute:

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES like '%dir';
+---------------------------+--------------------------+
| Variable_name             | Value                    |
+---------------------------+--------------------------+
| basedir                   | /usr/local/mysql         |
| datadir                   | /usr/local/mysql/data/   |
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call outside programs from within MySQL code.  It is not allowed because of the serious security issues.